# Angularjs when middle mouse button clicked scope dispersed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im using ui-sref for changing state on dom. When user clicked on this reference scope is destroying what is the best practise about this case. I dont want to store current scope data in some array or something like that. Here is my code;

```
<td class="v-middle">
 <a ui-sref="app.customer-profile-details({id: '{{entry.profileId ? entry.profileId:0}}',
  operation:'update'})">
  <span class="text-primary">
   <strong><u>{{entry.last_interaction | date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm"}}</u>
   </strong></span>
 </a>
</td>
```

---

```
.state('app.customer-profile-details', {
                    url: '/customer-profile-details',
                    templateUrl: 'views/customer-profiles/customer-profile-details.html',
                    controller: 'CustomerProfileDetailsController',
                    data: {
                        title: 'customer-profile-details.TITLE',
                        icon: 'icon-user',
                        link: null,
                        back: 'app.customer-profiles'
                    },
                    params: {id: null, operation: null},
                    resolve: load([])
```

The code of my state of above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store the state on a service instead of on the scope